# WebStorm - how change CRLF line endings into LF

Tags: git, webstorm, line-endings

I have error with WebStorm IDE. 
In current project, team uses TSLint, for static code analysis. One of the rules, is

```
    "linebreak-style": [
      true,
      "LF"
    ],
```

Before every commit, I need to change line endings in every changed file, because line endings were CRLF. I see also, that files changed and commited by team members have this incorrect CRLF line endings.

I think, that somewhere in process, take place automatic conversion of line endings to wrong format.

In WebStorm, I setted line separator to Unix and macOs (\n)

Can I change something in WebStorm setup to always use LF line endings?

Maybe this problem is related with Git?

Here is my Git config

```
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    eol = lf
```

Other team members do not have this problem, that's why, I think, that is something wrong with my setup.

Comment: Are the line endings already wrong before you create a Git commit?

Comment: Yes, I have this problem with old files, that I pulled from repo.

Comment: No, I mean if you edit a file with Webstorm and save it, are the line endings correct or not? Before that file even goes into a Git commit.

Comment: In this case line endighs were incorrect (CRLF). Before commit, I must manually convert endings by "fix tslint errror".

Comment: So the problem is not directly related to Git.

Comment: @mkrieger1 but maybe with my local Git setup?

Comment: in WebStorm, line separator can be set in Code Style for all future new files (created by IDE itself) .. or can be converted for any file via `File | Line Separators` (can also be accessed via Status Bar). If it magically converts into another ... then it must be something outside of IDE (e.g. your Git settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible answer, is refresh all git repo files. This will convert all files to LF endings.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings

I'm afraid of loosing/overriding history of multiple files. Other possible option is cloning project again with correct Git setup.

At this moment I decided do not deal with this problem, because files, that I fixed, works ok. Even when someone from team make rewrite content of my files, after pull, line endings works ok.